# CSWcataloguesource.js plugin "add to map" button not working!

Tags: boundless-suite, geonetwork

I got stuck in using CSWcataloguesource plugin in my OpenGeoSuite custom application.
It shows all the layers available in geonetwork but when click the "add to map" button it shows the following error.

TypeError: c.getLayer is not a function

and m not able to add it as a overlay.
Does anyone have idea what this error?and does anyone have used this CSWcataloguesource plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pasting error messages from minified JavaScript is not sufficient to get an answer to this. You will have to run your app in debug mode (`suite-sdk debug myapp`), use your browser's developer tools, and see what "c" and "m" are in unminified JavaScript. Then update your question, pasting the stack traces from the developer tools. You will also need to include the configuration of your CSWcataloguesource.

Answer (score 2):

note that the way a layer can be accessed from a dublin core metadata record varies between implementations, in geonetwork usually one adds the layername in the onlineresource name attribute, in previous versions of geoext/gxp this was not well managed, but Bart recently fixed it in this commit,

https://github.com/opengeo/gxp/commit/61b2457cc0a20b04235cba17f93101f749945158

Be sure your implementation has this commit (and a related commit in geoext).

Or else check your metadata record, does it have a wms-server attached and a layername specified?